# Inherting from template abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual

I am new to c++.  Its my first time working with templates. I want to define some sort of interface with pure virtual functions, but the return types of those functions may vary depending on the derived classes. So I thought about using a template in the abstract class. I'm not sure if what I have is even valid. I have something like:

```
template <class T> class InterfaceClass
{
  public:      
    virtual  T function1(const string& value)=0;
    virtual  T function2(const MyObj& p)=0;
}
```

So that I could inherit from it and define an interface to access the functions.

```
class myClass : public InterfaceClass<MyObj>{
     public:
         MyObj InterfaceClass::function1(const string& value)
         {
             MyObj a = parse(value);
         }
         MyObj InterfaceClass::function2(const MyObj& p)
         {
              return p;
         }
 }
```

The purpose is that I want to be available to do something like:

```
     InterfaceClass * pClass;
       if(isCertainType())
             pClass = new myClass();
       else 
             pClass = new myClass2();
```

The compiler is complaining that there is a redefinition of class `InterfaceClass`and that the functions members cannot be defined in `myClass`.  I am really confused at the moment  and would like to know if this is possible or what I am doing wrong. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the error message, together with the declaration of `myClass2`?

Comment: Don't mind the error I mentioned. it was because I forgot to #def the header file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is that when you inherit from template class with different arguments to the same template your classes have no common base class. (`InterfaceClass<int>` and `InterfaceClass<double>` are *different* classes).

As for virtuals, you just don't need to supply class name when defining them.

Comment: Basically, if you want different return type for functions in different classes that can be referred to using the same base classe, you can't do anything.

Comment: If you want to have "normal" abstract base class, you can create a base class, derive your class template from it and derive your classes from template classes.